# On a theorem of Nagata’s UFD criterion

Tags: commutative-algebra, proof-explanation, unique-factorization-domains

In [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-the-mathematical-society-of-japan/volume-9/issue-1/A-remark-on-the-unique-factorization-theorem/10.2969/jmsj/00910143.full) Nagata proves that if char$K$ ≠ 2 then $K[X_1,...,X_n]/(\sum X_i^2)$ is UFD for $n \geq 5$. There I have a doubt in the proof of the theorem 2. He is taking a height 1 prime ideal $p$ in $K[X_1,..,X_n]/(\mathfrak{a})$. Then why the ideal $pL[X_1,...,X_n]/(\mathfrak{a})$ has no embedded prime ? If $L$ is algebraic over $K$ then I can see it is true because of integral extension.

> [image]

Thanks..